# how to get needed parameters of a php method?

Tags: php

i write an api generator, and need to read all methods with ist parameters by a defined class. read all Methods is done!

Example Class:

```
class Foo {

    function tester($test)
    {
     return "bar";
    }

    function test(Article $article)
    {
     return "bar";
    } 

}

get_class_methods = array('tester', 'test');
```

ok, now i have to know the parameters of each function, how can i solve this problem?

Important is TypeHinting.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ok, now i have to know the parameters of each function, how can i solve this problem?

Using the [reflection API](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php). Build a new ReflectionClass( 'Foo' ), get the method test and you can get its parameters by getParameters( ). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is any method to do this, but you can use php lexical analyzer.

You may read the file using `token_get_all` (see http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php).
Then parse it by yourself to get all classes, methods, parameters, and even parse comments if you want!

Comment: Doctrine uses reflection, not the tokenizer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Zend_Reflection which is an extension to the PHP reflection classes.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.reflection.html

When you have a Zend_Reflection_Parameter object you can get your type hinting value thru getType I expect.